# Error when running pod install: Invalid attribute name

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am working with React Native (0.60.4) and cocoapods (1.7.5). When I cd into my ios folder and run pod install, I get the following error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] /Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/.bin/react-native config

Error: Invalid attribute name
Line: 36
Column: 18
Char: .
    at error (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
    at strictFail (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
    at SAXParser.write (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1324:13)
    at new XmlDocument (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js:199:15)
    at readManifest (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/config/readManifest.js:44:10)
    at Object.projectConfig (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/config/index.js:60:46)
    at Object.get project [as project] (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/index.js:134:65)
    at /Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/config/config.js:8:452
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _objectSpread (/Users/stephensmac_air/Documents/WeeklyTasks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/config/config.js:8:392)
```

My Podfile in my ios folder is the following:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'WeeklyTasks' do
  # Pods for WeeklyTasks
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  target 'WeeklyTasksTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'WeeklyTasks-tvOS' do
  # Pods for WeeklyTasks-tvOS

  target 'WeeklyTasks-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Anyone know what this error is trying to say? Before this I was trying to implement push notifications and I needed to run pod install and this ended up happening. Seems like maybe there is a syntax problem in the Podfile that I'm not noticing? If someone can point me in the general direction of what this could potentially be, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, did you copy/past your podfile exactly as it is, or you left out some of your comments at the top of anything?

Comment: No clue, but 1. I searched for `.` in your podfile, but don't see it used in your podfile. I **think** the error is about an incorrect character in the actual pod itself and has nothing to do with your podfile. If I were you I'd use version control to narrow down  changes and even to be sure I'd add a dummy `.` in the podfile to see what that error looks like. 2. FWIW sometimes characters get messed up due to copy/paste from different environments e.g. `"` is slack my get messed up. The only way I get it to work is to make sure my keyboard is English and then I start typing it all over again.

Comment: @Honey yes I copied/pasted my Podfile as is. I also added the . to check and I did get a different error that explicitly stated that there was a syntax error. I retraced my steps and you were right that it was a pod rather than the podfile. it turns out I needed to use a different notification pod than the one I was trying to use due to some changes with the package I was using that were related to the 0.60 version of react native. It works now, thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall cocoa pods (all versions) and then do a fresh installation.

Create a test project for react-native and the try pod commands, if everything works fine then try on the actual project(Keep a back up of code first).

Comment: are you saying its no longer needed to supply use_native_modules? Otherwise I am not sure commenting this line out is the right idea...